# Como deixar um elemento com a altura da página o tempo todo?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho o seguinte problema: Preciso deixar que uma div tenha o a altura da tela o tempo.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="topo">...</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" id="menulateral"> ...</div>
   <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12" id="principal"> ... </div>
</div>
```

Quero apenas fazer com o que a div com o identificador `menulateral` tenha o tempo todo a altura da tela.

Estava tentando fazer do seguinte jeito:

```
var altura = $("body").height();
$("#menulateral").height(altura);
```

Não sei se esse é o melhor jeito para eu fazer, porque gostaria que isso funcionasse sem problemas e em todos os dispositivos que pudessem acessar essa página. Existe uma solução melhor e mais confiável?

Comment: Você está usando _bootstrap_ no teu projeto?

Comment: sim estou bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem necessidade de utilizar Javascript se você não pretende fazer uso desse valor durante a execução da sua aplicação. Como bem disse, esse menu terá o mesmo tamanho sempre, então basta a propriedade `height` das CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

aside {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  height: 100%; /* 100% da altura do elemento pai (no caso, o 'body') */
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<aside></aside>
```

Mas se quiser mesmo usar jQuery, além de definir o tamanho inicial (como fez no seu código), também precisará ouvir pelos eventos de redimensionamento da janela para atualizar o tamanho do elemento:

```js
$(function() {

  var aside = $('aside');

  // Defininindo a altura inicial.
  aside.height($('body').height());

  // Redefinindo a altura sempre que a janela for redimensionada.
  $(window).resize(function() {
    aside.height($('body').height());
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

aside {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<aside>sopt</aside>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Vou te sugerir utilizar um modelo de página com menu lateral que o
>   próprio bootstrap sugere, [Simple
>   sidebar](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/)

Como você está fazendo, o `menulateral` está dentro de uma `row`, o que não é recomendável, pois a `row` é uma divisão na horizontal e seu menu precisa ser vertical.

O código é basicamente esse:

```
<body>    
    <div id="wrapper">    
        <!-- Sidebar - No seu exemplo, esse seria o seu menu lateral -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">

        </div>    
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <!-- Aqui vai o conteúdo da sua página -->
        </div>    
    </div> 
</body>
```

Da uma olhada no link do [template](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/)

> O `sidebar-wrapper` dentro de um `wrapper` irá criar um "espaço" para
>   um menu responsivo com 250px de largura. Seria bacana você dar uma
>   olhada no [html do
>   template](https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/blob/gh-pages/index.html)
>   e na documentação do
>   [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/), você não
>   precisa usar jQuery para isso. Claro, você pode fazer isso com jQuery,
>   mas acho que fica mais fácil e viável utilizando CSS e como disse no
>   começo, é uma sugestão.

Comment: entendi, então esse sidebar-wrapper já resolveria meu caso?

Comment: Alterei a resposta.